# CSS background image offset + contain doesn't take the whole width

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have an image that was provided to me, it has a width of 2400px and a height of 1000px

In the exact middle of this image is a red ball. Now the requirement is so that I use this image as a background image for a header, and that the red ball is positioned a bit to the right of the center.

My header is 100% width and has a height of 450px. When I put the background position to `center center` then it's completely centered, as expected. So I need a bit of an offset, which I did using the `calc()` function, but that gives me an 80px gap on the left side.

This is the code I used:

```
.header {
  background-image: url('../img/header.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(50% + 80px) 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 450px;
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve: the image should still be covering the whole header (unless you have a viewport wider than 2400px, but that's a different matter altogether) but it should be positioned a bit to the right, while ideally keeping it responsive. Is this possible and if yes, any idea how to move forward?

Comment: if you want to hide extra space taken on horizontal you can use `overflow-x:hidden;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the background image 160px (= two times 80px) wider than 100% to compensate for the missing 80px / the gap on the left side. But of course, then you can't use `contain` anymore - however, that won't be possible anyway with the requirements you have

```
.header {
  background-image: url('../img/header.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(50% + 80px) 50%;
  background-size: calc(100% + 160px) auto;
  height: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it but:

`background-size: cover;`
Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

`background-size: 100% 100%;`
Sets the width and height of the background image. The first value sets the width, the second value sets the height.

If the image has an even background, maybe you could use `background-repeat: repeat;`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

put the background size cover and background size 100% 100%